# Why doesn't the document get modified until it's out of the loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```js
while (prompt() !== "quit") {
    document.write("test ");
}
```

I'm expecting this JavaScript to modify the page behind the dialog each time I write something that's not `quit`.

However it doesn't do so until I do type `quit`. (Then I see a bunch of `test`s.)
What am I exactly missing?

Comment: What do you mean by `modify the document`? It just prints `test` until you type `quit`.

Comment: This seem browser related. on FireFox/ubuntu you have the `test` that show behind the alert box.

Comment: @Blag On Chrome/Mac and Firefox/Mac too. Please answer my question so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @Yassine Thank ! good to know this kind of behaviour can happen with Safari...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The refresh of the view behind your alert box seem browser related.

Some will update it between two alert box (as my Firefox on Ubuntu), but your may wait the closing of your alert box before generating the new frame view.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript while loop will check the condition `(prompt() !== "quit")` before running `document.write("test ");` that is why you aren't seeing the document modified.

Answer (score 0):

It won't execute the loop body until you have typed something into the prompt and clicked enter:

```
while (prompt() !== "quit") {
    document.write("test "); //waiting for prompt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the way `prompt` works - it blocks everything else on the page before you close it. And since you're calling it in your condition statement, it has to be evaluated before the code decides whether it goes inside the loop or not. It cannot predict whether you'll type `"quit"` or not. that's why it waits for your input first.

---

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

> Dialog boxes are modal windows; they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed. For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a dialog box (or modal window).

Comment: Even after I type something (other than "quit"), "test " doesn't get writed until I type "quit".

Comment: Hmmm, on my Chrome/Ubuntu (also Chrome/Debian) it writes "test" every time I input something that's not "quit", just as you'd expect it.